# jQuery TypeError:function not found error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get some properties of one of my `div` via following code

```
(function ($) {
function StickyNotes() {

    this.getProperties = function (note) {
        var properties = {};
        properties['top'] = note.position().top;
        properties['from_center'] = this.calcFromCenter(note.position().left);
        properties['width'] = note.find(".resize").width();
        properties['height'] = note.find(".resize").height();
        return properties;
    }

    this.saveBoardAndNotes = function (board_id, board_name) {
        var noteList = new Array();

        $(".optimal-sticky-notes-sticker-note").each(function(){
            // Replace plain urls with links and improve html
            var note = $(this);
            content = note.find(".textarea").html();
            noteID = note.attr("id");
            properties = JSON.stringify(this.getProperties(note));

        });

    }
}

var StickyNotes = new StickyNotes();

jQuery(document).ready(function (e) {

    $('#sticky-notes-add-board').click(function (e) {
        if(confirm('Do you want to save previous board?')) {
            var board_id = $('.optimal-sticky-notes-board:last').attr('id');
            var board_name = $('.optimal-sticky-notes-board:last').text();
            StickyNotes.saveBoardAndNotes(board_id, board_name);
        }
    })


});})(jQuery);
```

But I get following error..

```
TypeError: this.getProperties is not a function
```

I filtered all data like content and noteID. They are showing. But problem with `this.getProperties`. How can i solve the problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `each` loop `this` points to current `optimal-sticky-notes-sticker-note` div. One of the several ways to reference correct scope is to use variable pointing to outer `this`:

```
this.saveBoardAndNotes = function (board_id, board_name) {
    var noteList = new Array();
    var self = this;

    $(".optimal-sticky-notes-sticker-note").each(function(){
        // Replace plain urls with links and improve html
        var note = $(this);
        content = note.find(".textarea").html();
        noteID = note.attr("id");
        properties = JSON.stringify(self.getProperties(note));
    });
}
```